# Azure Data Engineer Associate certificate - preparation, Microsoft learn platform

Tags: azure, certificate

Does anyone tried to prepare for Azure Data Engineer Associate certificate with Microsoft's online training? My concern is about a scope of proposed training and skills outline document. One thing what I saw in that document (maybe there is more) are questions about Databricks and in online training there is no module for Databricks. So is that learning path enough to pass that exams (DP-200, DP-201)? If not what else is missing in that path? Any suggestions for other free online learning courses.

learing path: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/certifications/azure-data-engineer

Answer (score 1):

I finished this learning path. Yes, as you say. there is no Databricks content in this path. I would suggest you to provision Databricks on Azure - hopefully using free credit - and try it out. Here is what I suggest.

- Load data into Gen 2 Storage - ideally parquet files.
- Create a Databricks cluster and mount Gen 2 storage on DBFS.
- Create a notebook and access parquet files and make few transformations using spark data-frames.
- On Synapse, create external tables using parquet files from above step.

This should help you understand lot of topics and get you ready for the exam.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend checking out the **'Mr.K Talks Tech'** channel for exceptional **Azure Data Engineering tutorials**. The content is incredibly helpful, and what sets it apart is the inclusion of **real-time project videos**, making it easier for everyone to understand. Dive into practical examples and enhance your Azure Data Engineering skills. Don't miss out on this valuable resource!

For easy access to video, click on the link below:
https://youtu.be/iQ41WqhHglk?si=RH_uxYxlLe6YT4Vu

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35699463)

Comment: Additionally, this seems on topic but reads like spam.